How to resolve unauthorized issue to access azure function app - using postman token - google oauth2
I have a function app, with Identity provider as google. (Authentication)
In google I have OAuth2 client id configured
Authorised JavaScript origins
http://localhost:3000
https://i***.5.azurestaticapps.net
https://l***ons.azurewebsites.net

Authorised redirect URIs
http://localhost:3000
https://i***.5.azurestaticapps.net/.auth/login/google/callback
https://l***ons.azurewebsites.net
https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback

In postman a request was created  similar to 
Callback URL: Set to https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback (default for Postman).
Auth url : https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
Access token url: https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
Client ID: Enter the Client ID from Google Cloud Console.
Client Secret: Enter the Client Secret from Google Cloud Console.
Scope: Set the scope to openid email profile to retrieve the user’s profile information.
Action: Get new  Access token
Token generation is ok. ( I entered credentials, google popup, and then postman popup with details to "use token")
Now, in another postman request (to invoke function app)
I have pasted function app endpoint
In the Authorization tab, set the Type to Bearer Token and paste the access token obtained from Google.
**I have a doubt here...should I use Access Token or id_token  ( I tried both)
Outcome: Unauthorized
Where is the validation failing? How to troubleshoot the issue? please help

Can you share your code?

The code is just a simple function. The goal to make it secure using Authentication feature of Azure (also called EasyAuth?) The code is just Hello, like this https://github.com/azure-samples/azure-functions-samples-java/blob/master/triggers-bindings/src/main/java/com/functions/Function.java

Steps on how I created function: In Intellij created a new project ...selected maven archetype suggested for azure function , packaged and deployed. A few changes are in pom around resource group, region etc. nothing related to source

Ok, I will try from my end and let you know.
